# Favicon.ico in Django app cannot be found resulting in 502 Error

Tags: python, django, passenger, wsgi, favicon

I'm completely stumped. I have written a Django application that is being hosted by A2 and is served up through passenger wsgi. It functions in development, but on deployment, it fails with the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
/favicon.ico:1

So, I figure that the favicon must not be able to be found by the application. I have an index.html that contains the following in the head:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'icons/favicon.ico' %}" 
type="image/x-icon" />
```

That doesn't seem to do it. I tried adding it to my app.urls as a view like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings

favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='static/favicon.ico', 
permanent=False)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('resume/', include('resume.urls')),
    path('favicon.ico', favicon_view),
]
```

Works in dev again, not in deployment. I'm not sure if it is a problem with my static folder or what. I understand that there's loads of threads about favicon.ico, but none seem to be much relevant (for Ruby on Rails) or I have already tried the solutions above, which failed. Any ideas on how to get past this favicon.ico 502 error?

Here is my relevant settings.py code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tmp')
```

And here is my project tree with the attempted locations of favicon.ico:

```
app
- app
  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
- public
  - icons/favicon.ico
- resume
  - static
    - icons/favicon.ico
    - favicon.ico
  - templates
  - templatetags
  - (python files)
- tmp
  - (empty)
- favicon.ico
- manage.py
- passenger_wsgi.py
```

Comment: Looks like you need to include the icon in `static/icons/roger.ico`.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I had changed it and used older code. Revised.
The problem arose from the expectation that favicon.ico exists somewhere, I didn't originally have it in my code or as a file. But it still doesn't resolve the error, unfortunately.